# Proving that continuous periodic function on R is bounded and uniformly conutious on R

Tags: real-analysis

So using the definition of periodic function which is there exist $p \neq 0$ such that $f(x+p) = f(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
I know that I only need to prove on the interval $[a,b]$ which other part of the function just repeats what it looks like on the interval $[a,b]$.
Where do I go from here?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Extreme Value Theorem? That should help you show that it  is bounded.

Comment: Any continuous function is uniformly continuous on a closed bounded interval.

Comment: The image of a compact set through a continuous function is compact :)

Comment: The map from R to R factor through circle. As continuous functions on compact set have the two properties, so do periodic functions.